# Directory listings of ext4 image by python

Tags: python, image, filesystems, ext4, listings

I have an image of the disk with the ext4 file system and i need to implement the utility to read the files and view directory listings *by python*. How i can do it without mounting the image?

Please, give me some hints, i realy don't know where to start.

Comment: I reliezed that it would be easier by mounting an image :) Just on unix and windows it needs to do in different ways.

Comment: My thought exactly from the very beginning. :-)